# Facebook iOS sdk 4.2 get feed from a friend's profile

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the feed from a friend's profile. Is there any way to do that?

I'm trying the endpoint below, but I get nothing.

```
friendId/feed
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to retrieve information about a user's friends unless those friends also use your app - this [change was introduced in Graph API v2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0) and since 2015-04-30, v2.0 is the minimum version so this applies to all apps

Comment: How would I do it if the friend uses my app? Keeping in mind that FB ids are now ephemeral.

Comment: If the friend uses the app and both users granted user_friends permission, you know both their id and whether the users are friends, AFAIK /<friend>/feed will work in that case if you include an app_secret_proof (that would need to be a sever side call, though)